# Incremently load big RDD file into memory

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

```
val locations = filelines.map(line => line.split("\t")).map(t => (t(5).toLong, (t(2).toDouble, t(3).toDouble))).distinct().collect() 


val cartesienProduct=locations.cartesian(locations).map(t=> Edge(t._1._1,t._2._1,distanceAmongPoints(t._1._2._1,t._1._2._2,t._2._2._1,t._2._2._2)))
```

Code executes perfectly fine up till here but when i try to use "cartesienProduct" it got stuck i.e.

```
val count =cartesienProduct.count()
```

Any help to efficiently do this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The rdd-transformations `locations.cartesian(locations)` and `map` are lazy. They get applied when an rdd-action such as `count` is called. So it is normal that the program will take more time at this step.

Comment: Yes i understand that. However, any suggestions/ alternate to approach to perform same tasks ?

Comment: How big is the data set you're developing for?

Comment: The data set is approx. 700 GB

Answer (score 0):

First, the map transformation can be made more readable if written as:

```
locations.cartesian(locations).map { 
  case ((a1, (b1, c1)), (a2, (b2, c2)) => 
       Edge(a1, a2, distanceAmongPoints(b1,c1,b2,c2)))
}
```

It seems the objective is to calculate distance between two points for all pairs. cartesian will give the pair twice, effectively computing same distance twice.

To avoid that, one approach could be to broadcast a copy of all points and then compare in parts.

```
val points: // an array of points.

val pointsRDD = sc.parallelize(points.zipWithIndex)

val bPoints = sc.broadcast(points)

pointsRDD.map { case (point, index) => 
   (index + 1 until bPoints.value.size).map { i =>  
      distanceBetweenPoints(point, bPoints.value.get(i))
   }
}
```

If size of points is N, it will compare point-0 with (point-1 to point-N-1), point-1 with (point-2 to point-N-1) etc.